# Mismatch in entityRanges with emoji as presiding text to mentions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

i am using mentions plugin it works awesome as expected without emojis/unicode.

My situations

ex: " dude Suresh Chandrababu" is my text in editor. Suresh Chandrababu is mention.

I need to extract the mention offset position, length and send to my API, problem here is when emojis/unicode added before the mentions, offset returned by Draft editor was wrong.

Expected o/p: entityRange - offset:3, length: 18
Actual o/p: entityRange - offset:2, length: 18

Emoji's length is 2, but entityRange consider it as 1.

How to handle this situation.

o/p:[image]

Comment: how 'Emoji's length is 2'?

Comment: "".length gives you the length.

Comment: that is one character for GUI editor, even the length is 2 in JS.

Comment: thats my problem, when i take the entityRange of mentions from convertToRaw function it gives me wrong range of mentions.

Comment: @JiangYD any solution?